# JAVA. My nested for loop which I made to insert integers in array from another array skips the whole part except the first and the last values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

For my homework we have to create a Grid class and one of the methods is *setCells(int rows[], int cols[], int vals[])*, where user can specify the indexes of rows and columns that the user wants to set with some particular values (supplied in vals array). Note that, rows, cols, and vals arrays should be of same size.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
public void setCells(int rowsArray[ ], int columnsArray[ ], int valuesArray[ ]) {
    for (int rows = 0; rows < rowsArray.length; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < columnsArray.length; columns++) {
            for (int values = 0; values < valuesArray.length; values++) {
                setValue(rows, columns, valuesArray[values]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the main, I've checked if this segment works. Here's the part of code for it:

```
int[] valuesArray = new int[]{1, 222, 3, 45, 4, 99};
Grid lol = new Grid(11);

    lol.setCells(new int[5], new int[5], valuesArray);
    lol.getValue(4,4);
    lol.getValue(3,3);
    lol.getValue(2,2);
    lol.getValue(1,1);
    lol.getValue(0,0);
```

this is the output.

> 99
>   99
>   99
>   99
>   1

I think something is wrong with the logic of nested loop.
This is my first year in programming, so I've been thinking about this for 3 hours. I'll be glad if can help me find the mistake in the code.

EDITED.
Full Grid Class:

```
    public class Grid {
private int value;
private int[][] grid;

public Grid(int height, int width) {
    if (height == width) {
        grid = new int[height][width];
    } else{
        System.out.println("Height and width should be equal");
    }
}

public Grid(int size) {
      grid = new int[size][size];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    boolean empty = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < grid.length; p++) {
            if (grid[i][p] != 0) {
                empty = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!empty) {
            System.out.println("Grid is not empty");
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (true)
        System.out.println("Grid is empty");
        return true;
}

public void Clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < grid.length; p++) {
            grid[i][p] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public boolean isValid(int rows, int columns) {
    if(grid[rows][columns] == 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void setValue(int rows, int columns, int value) {
    if (isValid(rows, columns)) {
        grid[rows][columns] = value;
        } else if(!isValid(rows, columns) && rows < grid.length && columns < grid.length) {
            grid[rows+1][columns+1] = value;
        }
    }

public int getValue(int rows, int columns){
    if(rows >= 0 && rows <= grid.length && columns >= 0 && columns <= grid.length ){
        System.out.println(grid[rows][columns]);
    }
    return value;
}

public void setCells(int rowsArray[], int columnsArray[], int valuesArray[]) {
    for (int rows = 0; rows < rowsArray.length; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < columnsArray.length; columns++) {
            for (int values = 0; values < valuesArray.length; values++) {
                setValue(rows, columns, valuesArray[values]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full main:

```
public class GridTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] valuesArray = new int[]{1, 222, 3, 45, 4, 99};
    Grid kek = new Grid(10,10);
    Grid lol = new Grid(11);

    kek.isEmpty();
    lol.isEmpty();

    if(kek.isValid(4,5)){
        System.out.println("\nTrue");
    }
    if(lol.isValid(6,1)){
        System.out.println("\nTrue");
    }

    kek.setValue(4, 5, 52);
    kek.getValue(4,5);
    if(!kek.isValid(4,5)){
        System.out.println("False");
    }
    kek.setValue(4,5,5);
    kek.getValue(5,6);

    System.out.println();
    kek.isEmpty();

    kek.Clear();
    if(kek.isValid(4,5)){
        System.out.println("\nTrue");
    }
    kek.isEmpty();

    System.out.println();
    lol.setCells(new int[5], new int[5], valuesArray);
    lol.getValue(4,4);
    lol.getValue(3,3);
    lol.getValue(2,2);
    lol.getValue(1,1);
    lol.getValue(0,0);
```

Full output:

Grid is empty
Grid is empty

True

True
52
False
5

Grid is not empty

True
Grid is empty

99
99
99
99
1

1

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please add the expect output, it's clear than describe your goal.

Comment: Unfortunately, my teacher hasn't given me one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you intended this:

```
public void setCells(int rowsArray[ ], int columnsArray[ ], int valuesArray[ ]) {
    for (int i= 0; i< rowsArray.length; i++) {                  
        setValue(rowsArray[i], columnsArray[i], valuesArray[i]);    
    }
}
```

Also in your test code the rowsArray and valuesArray are both filled with zeroes since you did not set any values.

I would expect test code like this:

```
int[] valuesArray = new int[] {12, 222, 31, 45, 42, 99};
int[] rowsArray = new int[] {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
int[] columnsArray = new int[] {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
Grid lol = new Grid(11);    
lol.setCells(rowsArray , columnsArray, valuesArray);
lol.getValue(5,5);
lol.getValue(4,4);
lol.getValue(3,3);
lol.getValue(2,2);
lol.getValue(1,1);
lol.getValue(0,0);
```

BTW a nicer way to model this would be using a separate class to represent one set of user input:

```
class UserInput {
    private final int row;
    private final int col;
    private final int value;

    UserInput (int row, int col, int value) { 
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.val = val;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Every time the user enters a new row/col/val you create a new UserInput instance and add it to a list:

```
List<UserInput> inputs = new UserInput<>();    

// for each set of user input do:

inputs.add(new UserInput(row, col, val));
```

Then to set the entries in the grid:

```
for (UserInput i: inputs) {                  
    setValue(i.getRow(), i.getCol(), i.getValue());    
}
```

You can remove the 2-args constructor since your grid must always be square.

Your code is pretty flawed. I think isValid should probably also check for the grid size. What is the setValue method supposed to do? Increase both the row and column index if a cell is already filled? And what if that cell is also already filled? You don't need the second !isValid check in the else (you just checked for isValid in the if).

Please take some more time to think about the logic of your code.

Next time, post the full code straight away to save us all some time.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. 
So I have to delete loops and create 2 more arrays(such as valuesArray) in main with coordinates. Then use the coordinates to change values, right?

Comment: However, I need a loop to loop through this "coordinates".

Comment: Now it's much better. My input is like this: 12
0
31
0
42
0

Comment: Thank you for helping. But my teacher hates when we use things we haven't studied yet, so I can't use lists.

Comment: Also input is still strange. Now it skips 3 values:\

Comment: You never explained what your code should do so I cannot really help you further.

Comment: Btw, you don't need second i++. It breaks the code and logic, as well.

Comment: ah sry. that was a little unintended easter egg. :-D Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

In your innermost loop you are writing all values of the valuesArray to the same cell which doesn’t make sense, i.e when row is 2 and column is 3 you first set that cell to 1 then to 222 and so on ending it with 99.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking about. 
However, I don't know how to rewrite those loops to avoid that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely this output will be expected because in your `setCells()` method you are writing all the values of `valuesArray[]` on the same cell.

suppose the counter values for rows = 0 and columns = 0 and in the 3rd for loop it will iterate for all values and put values on same cell i.e. grid[0][0] = 1 then grid[0][0] = 222 ans so on till the last value will replace it to grid[0][0] = 99.

So every time for every cell only last value i.e. 99 will be placed